# Why am I getting a 'cross-device link not permitted' error in Docker on Gitlab CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm, gitlab

I tried deleting the node_modules folder, but I'm still getting the error. It was working fine, but suddenly has started throwing this error.

It's a react app, if that helps.

Docker file

```
## Stage 0, "builder", based on Node.js, to build and compile the frontend
# base image
FROM node:alpine as builder

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

## add app
COPY . /app

# delete node modules to fix discrepancies
RUN rm -rf node_modules/

#RUN npm install && npm audit fix && npm audit fix --force && npm install
RUN npm install -g npm@7.0.3 && npm install && npm audit fix
RUN npm run build 

## Stage 1, "deployer", use nginx to deploy the code
## start app
FROM nginx:alpine

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html/

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

console errors

```
npm notice 
npm notice New patch version of npm available! 7.0.2 -> 7.0.3
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.0.3>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@7.0.3` to update!
npm notice 
npm ERR! code EXDEV
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI
npm ERR! errno -18
npm ERR! EXDEV: cross-device link not permitted, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-10-23T16_47_42_554Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install -g npm@7.0.3 && npm install && npm audit fix' returned a non-zero code: 238
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, it might actually be a bug in npm 7. But i can't confirm.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. Since your base image is node, npm should already be globally installed. There is no need to run `npm install -g npm@7.0.3` and still be able to execute all npm related items afterwards.

Comment: I might be wrong but that seems to be just notices, the errors seem to be comming after the install of packages isnt it? I will try removing the line and check if it works. Thanks

Comment: Running `npm install -g npm@latest` might be required to update npm to the latest version after installing NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not enough rep to comment.

I actually ran into similar issues as well. Node's been updated which has bumped the npm version up to 7+, which seems to be causing people issues. My solution until I can fully flesh out the issues has been to version lock my Node/NPM within my container build.

`FROM node:14.14-alpine3.11` is the instruction I'm using, keeps me at some 6.x.x version to keep my builds working.