# EXDEV: cross-device link not permitted, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI'

Tags: node.js, circleci

My builds keep failing on CircleCI with the error:

```sh
EXDEV: cross-device link not permitted, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI'
```

This happens before installing any library. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In docker on gitlab CI/CD pipeline getting this error, any ideas how to solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64504721/in-docker-on-gitlab-ci-cd-pipeline-getting-this-error-any-ideas-how-to-solve-it)

Answer (score 5):

In my case the reason for this and also some other errors was the release of node 15 and its use in `FROM node:alpine` -> downgrading to `FROM node:14.14.0-alpine` worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned somehow this seems to be related to using Node 15. In my case I was using the latest Node docker image in my .circleci/config.yml:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:latest
```

The other answers so far have suggested hardcoding a specific node version but I'm generally wary of hardcoding. As an alternative I decided to use the most recent LTS version of Node:

```yaml
      - image: circleci/node:lts
```

This fixes the issue and I think it's probably better since it should give me a more stable release to test against moving forward.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem when trying to update npm using

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

I decided to use Node Version Manager instead, so that I can set the node version as I need and its also only working solution for me.

My configuration looks like this:

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: 'circleci/node:latest'
    environment:
      NODE_VERSION: v12.18.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: set node version
          command: |
            set +e             
            touch $BASH_ENV  
            curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.36.0/install.sh | bash
            echo 'export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"' >> $BASH_ENV
            echo '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"' >> $BASH_ENV
            echo 'nvm install $NODE_VERSION' >> $BASH_ENV
            echo 'nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION' >> $BASH_ENV
      - run:
          name: npm install project dependencies
          command:
            npm install
      - run:
          name: lint
          command:
            npm run lint
```

Comment: You're using a docker image that already has node installed (`circleci/node`) and then you're installing node again using nvm. If you're going to use nvm to install node it would be better to use a docker image that doesn't already have node installed.